# SQL Server Replication between a domain and VLAN

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014

I have a requirement to replicate data between two sql server 2014 instances, one of the instance is in our production domain and second instance is in a separate VLAN.

Is it possible to configure replicaiton ? if so, is there any way to open connection only unidirectional , from production domain to VLAN ? does it require bidirectional network connection like subscriber (here sql instance in VLAN) should also need access to publisher (here production domain) ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to configure replicaiton ?

Yes.

> if so, is there any way to open connection only unidirectional , from production domain to VLAN ?

Packet-flow must, of course, work in both directions.  If the Distributor can connect to both the Publisher and Subscriber, you can use [Push Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/create-a-push-subscription).  With a Push Subscription all the processes run on the Distributor, and the Subscriber would never need to connect to the Publisher or Distributor.

Comment: ok thanks David. so if Distribution database is in publisher instance, then we need to open ports between both servers, right ?

Comment: You wouldn't need an inbound firewall rule on the Publisher/Distributor as the connections would all be outbound to the Subscriber.

Comment: thanks again...so distributor doesn't wait for ack or message from subscriber once the records are transferred to subscriber ?

Comment: Yes.  The Distributor will open a TCP/IP connection to the Subscriber and use TDS to communicate.  It's normal SQL Server client connectivity from the Distributor to the Subscriber, and definitely requires IP packets to travel both ways between the Subscriber and the Distributor over the established TCP/IP connection.

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt response....sorry for so many questions it's kind of confusing to me....when you say, "It's normal SQL Server client connectivity from the Distributor to the Subscriber, and definitely requires IP packets to travel both ways between the Subscriber and the Distributor over the established TCP/IP connection."  so does it work if i open port 1433 of VLAN in production domain ? or do i have to open port 1433 in VLAN as well ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64200/discussion-between-robin16-and-david-browne-microsoft).